# Free codecs: How to use FFmpeg to convert my mp4s to ogv under Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, ffmpeg, batch, transcode, free-software

I am very attracted to the idea of using completely *free* codecs. How do I convert my `.mp4` files to `.ogv` using FFmpeg under Xenial Xerus using these free codecs?

I am interested in:

1. Converting a single mp4 file
2. Converting a folder with many mp4 files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install FFmpeg by running the following in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Then change to *the same folder* as your mp4 file(s) and run either of the following:

**1. For a *single* mp4 file:**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libtheora -qscale:v 6 -c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 output.ogv
```

Of course change `input.mp4` to the actual filename of *your* input video file!

**2. For *many* mp4 files:**

```
mkdir ogv && \
for j in *.mp4
do 
 ffmpeg -i "$j" -c:v libtheora -qscale:v 6 -c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 ogv/"${j%.mp4}.ogv"
done
```

Options to experiment with:

- `-qscale:v` (for video quality) takes integers from 0 - 10 with 0 being lowest quality and 10 the highest quality
- `-qscale:a` (for audio quality) takes integers from 0 - 10 with 0 being lowest quality and 10 the highest quality

And enjoy the feeling of using libtheora and libvorbis, both codecs completely unencumbered and totally free :)

**References:**

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Theora & Vorbis](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide)