# WinFF: How to produce 'free' ogv files under Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, ffmpeg, free-software, winff

FFmpeg produces great ogv files under Xenial:

- [Free codecs: How to use FFmpeg to convert my mp4s to ogv under Xenial?](https://askubuntu.com/q/797724/57576)

But I would like to use the gui WinFF to produce these files, and WinFF has no presets for this purpose. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *default* installation of WinFF under Xenial:

```
sudo apt-get install winff ffmpeg
```

has no presets to produce ogv files with Theora video and Vorbis sound. A great omission IMHO.

You can rectify this omission by producing a text file called `ogv.wff` on your Desktop and placing the following contents into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<presets> 
  <OGV>
    <label>Theora encoding with Vorbis sound</label>
    <params>-c:v libtheora -qscale:v 6 -c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 </params>
    <extension>ogv</extension>
    <category>My Presets</category>
  </OGV>
</presets>
```

Save this file, close it, right click on it and select: 'Open with WinFF' and this is enough to save your new preset in `~/.winff/presets.xml`.

And now you can enjoy producing great quality media files with 2 completely free codecs!

**References:**

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Theora & Vorbis](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide)